# SQL Server query select loop the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with the query.

I have 2 table, table person and table income

I need to query like this:

```
ID | Name | Income A | Income B | Income C | .... | ...

ID | Name = from table person
Income A | Income B | Income C = loop from table income
```

In table income, there is the income name and income value

```
Name     | Value
---------+-------
Income A | 100
Income B | 200
Income C | 300
```

I have a third table, where the tables save id person and id income. So if a person has 3 incomes and another person has 2 incomes, then the result where the person have 2 income, the income fill with 0

Example

```
ID | Name   | income A | Income B | income C
---+--------+----------+----------+---------
1  | andre  |  100     |  200     |  300
2  | robert |  100     |  200     |    0
```

Hope you guys understand what I mean

Comment: How are the tables connected?

Comment: ow sorry, i have third table, where the tables save id person and id income. so if a person have 3 income and another person have 2 income then the result where the person have 2 income, the income fill with 0

Comment: Add that to your question please. Obviously we need it.

Comment: In general, we don't write loops in SQL. It looks like what you need here are *join*s.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can you give me the example? thx

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @pivot varchar(60);
DECLARE @sql varchar(6000);
SET @pivot=(SELECT Stuff(
  (SELECT N', [' + T.Name+']' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM income) T FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N''));

--  PRINT @pivot;
SET @sql='select * from income pivot (avg(Value) 
          for Name in ('+@pivot+')) as incomes';           


EXECUTE(@sql);

then join with other table and convert join null with 0
```